# Trying to stay DRY in Django: Refactoring repetitive code in Views

Tags: django, view, refactoring, decorator, dry

I have a lot of different list views for tables.  Each view differs only in the template used.  My only successful strategy involves using a decorator containing the common code and then returning 'pass' for the view function.  The problem I face is if I want to add individual code to a specific list view that differs from the others.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Here is my decorator:

```
def my_decorator(html=""):
    def my_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            bacteria = Bacteria.objects.all()
            bacteria_count = bacteria.count()

            bacteriaFilter = BacteriaFilter(request.GET, queryset=bacteria)
            bacteria = bacteriaFilter.qs
            remaining = bacteria.count()
            common_tags = Bacteria.tags.most_common()[:8]
            '''
            context = {"bacteria": bacteria, 'common_tags': common_tags, 'bacteria_count': bacteria_count,
                 'bacteriaFilter': bacteriaFilter, 'remaining': remaining}
            '''
            return render(request, html, locals())
        return wrapper
    return my_decorator
```

And here are several examples (I have over 15 tables) of the list view functions:

```
@my_decorator(html="bacteria/generalPhysiology.html")
def general_physiology_view(request):
    pass


@my_decorator(html="bacteria/enzymeActiveTable.html")
def enzyme_activity_table_view(request):
    pass
```

Comment: Use class based views and inheritance, have you used them before?

Comment: Hi Iain, thanks for the tip.  I had a look at CBV's with inheritance and it solved my problem.  It looks like class-based mixins offer more flexibility than decorators and it allows my view classes to take advantage of builtin Django generic views, such as ListView, which lets me paginate, for example.